# Formulating Conservation of Energy in Galilean Spacetime

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

**Some background to my question (Galilean spacetime).**

The notion of **Galilean spacetime** is defined at the beginning of Arnold's book on Classical Mechanics. It is a mathematical structure that captures the structure of spacetime (as understood by classical mechanics) which is independent of arbitrary choice of a reference frame. E.g., in Galilean spacetime one can define when two events are simultaneous (as time is absolute) but not when two non-simultaneous have the same spatial location (as this notion is relative).
Formally, a Galilean spacetime is a triplet $M=(\mathbb{A}^4,t,\|\cdot\|)$, where

- $\mathbb{A}^4$ is a $4$-dimensional affine space, acted upon by the vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$.
- $t:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a linear surjective mapping which defines the notion of time. Let $S$ denote its kernel; then $S$ can be thought of as the $3$-dimensional space of spatial displacements.
- $\|\cdot\|$ is a Euclidean norm on $S$, which defines the notion of distance.

One can then define motion in $M$, which will be a function $\mathbf{x}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^4$. Its ($4$-)velocity is a function $\mathbf{v}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ and it satisfies $t(\mathbf{v})=1$, and its acceleration turns out to be a function $\mathbf{a}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S$.

**My question.**

While concepts like force and momentum are easily definable in a Galilean spacetime $M$, I fail to see how to formulate in $M$ the notions of conservative forces and conservation of energy. The classic derivation of those concepts (in a given reference frame) relies on the assumption that $\mathbf{F}$ is solely a function of position $\mathbf{x}$. But this is very much frame-dependent. Switching to a moving frame seems to even break the definitions; however obviously there is still some quantity conserved. So **how can energy conservation be formulated in a frame-independent way?**

Comment: It is not possible, as the energy depends on the reference frame. Think of a spring attached to a mass and on a geometric point at rest with a reference frame. In that reference system the total  energy of the mass is conserved and the force of the spring is conservative. In another reference frame where the previous one has a given  velocity the force of the spring  is not conservative and energy is not conserved.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Indeed, but in the new reference frame there is still a physical quantity (the one we used to call energy, now expressed in with the new coordinates) which is conserved. The conservation equation will definitely look rather different, but the underlying physical phenomenon is still there.

Comment: @35T41: Yes, but when Einstein talked about covariance of physical phenomena he also meant that the mathematical expression should remain the same. If thecequation looks different in different frames, then thats not a physical law.

Comment: So conservation of energy is not a physical law? What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it is a physical law, but the hypotheses for its validity depend on the choice of the reference frame. I do not see the problem.

Comment: We are speaking of *classical physics*. Every physicists knows tha conservation of energy is a fundamental physical law, are we kidding?

Comment: In special or  general relativity conservation of energy  is subordinated to the choice of  a timelike Killing vector and that is the corresponding of a reference frame in classical physics.